# Best Excel chart for displaying discrete survey results

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have an Excel workbook containing results from a recent skillset survey.  For every skillset, respondents could choose from Low/Medium/High or they just leave it blank.

What is the best chart to display this data?  I was thinking possibly using a radar chart, but that would get very crowded with the number of skillsets listed.

I don't think using numerical equivalents (ex. scoring from 1-3) will work since 3 Low values wouldn't correspond to 1 High value, but I'm open to other suggestions.

Comment: sounds like you have 2 different asks. For chart selection: If you need to display all data at once then bar charts is the answer. If you can group measures then a radar might work. There may be a way to hover over a section of the radar to zoom into the details, might require a "better" BI tool to accomplish. The second ask to convert numerical values into text try this: https://www.automateexcel.com/charts/axis-text/